# Spark standalone HA mode, how to proxy all spark ui request to leader node

Tags: apache-spark, nginx, spark-ui

Env:

> spark 3.3.1
> nginx 1.18.0

I have two spark master node worked in HA mode, one is leaeer, another is standby. And I want use spark ui to view information about spark workers and spark drivers.
But the factor is , if I visit a spark ui on standby node, nothing displayed on the page, so I have to know which node is leader at first.
Does spark has a mechanism to redirect spark ui request to leader node ?
or is there a way to find which node is leader and proxy spark ui to leader node by nginx, and proxy all request to leader node.